# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Data Service return 2 cursor as out parameter (Oracle)

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

How to return 2 cursor which returns table *as out parameter* on **Wso2 DS** ?

When i return this, it does not recognize which *cursor(table)'s column*.

Comment: Can you use the wso2 integrator?

Comment: yes i am using it ?